# Hacking Lua - Inject new functions into built Lua

Tags: lua

I am trying to hack a game (not for cheating though) by introducing new built-in methods and functions in order to communicate with the game using sockets. Here is a small "pseudo code" example of what I want to accomplish:

Inside the Lua code I am calling `my_hack()` and pass the current game state:

```lua
GameState = {}

-- Game state object to be passed on
function GameState:new()
  -- Data
end

local gameState = GameState:new()
-- Collect game state data and pass it to 'my_hack' ..
my_hack(gameState)
```

and inside `my_hack` the object is getting sent away:

```cpp
int my_hack(lua_State * l)
{
   void* gameState= lua_topointer(l, 1);

   // Send the game state:
   socket->send_data(gameState);

   return 0;
}
```

---

Now, the big question is how to introduce `my_hack()` to the game?

I assume, that all built in functions must be kept in some sort of lookup table. Since all Lua code is getting interpreted, functions like `import` etc. will have to be statically available, right? If that is correct, then it should be "enough" to find out *where* this code is residing in order to smuggle my code into the game that would allow me to call `my_hack()` in a Lua script.

There should be two options: The first is that the Lua built is embedded inside the executable and is completely static and the second is that all Lua code gets loaded dynamically from a DLL.

This question goes out to anybody who has a slightest clue about where and how I should keep looking for the built in functions. I've tried a few things with Cheat Engine but I wasn't too successful. I was able to cheat a bit ^^ but that's not what I'm looking out for.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not providing a *full* answer, but if you can provide a custom Lua VM and change the standard libraries, you should be able to to change the `luaL_openlibs` method in the Lua source to provide a table with `my_hack()` inside of it.

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand but it sounds a bit impossible to do that. The game developers back then compiled their own version of Lua and packed it into the game. It sounds quite heavy to try and replace their Lua VM with my own inside a compiled game.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Lua interpreter is usually statically compiled into the host executable, modifying the interpreter in some way will probably not be possible.

I think your best bet is to find some piece of Lua code which gets called by the host, and from that file use `dofile` to run your own code.